# Which version of Rails works with Ruby 1.8.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a web server that hosts Ruby version 1.8.5.  Which version of Rails is compatible with that version of Ruby?  On the Rails site, it says that the pre-requisite for running Rails 3.0 is Ruby 1.8.7.  Does Rails 3.0 work at all with versions prior to 1.8.7?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [their site](http://rubyonrails.org/download):

> We recommend Ruby 1.8.7 or Ruby 1.9.2 for use with Rails. Ruby 1.8.6 and earlier are not supported, neither is version 1.9.1.

Which means, sure, you can use it. But you're on your own if it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: So you're saying that 1.8.5 will work but you can't guarentee everything working?  At the moment I don't think I can change the version of Ruby on the webserver.  At least I don't think I can.

Comment: Not me, they wont guarantee everything will work. There's probably some fundamental reason for it.